# Remote Desktop not working over wan

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10, remote-desktop

I'm trying to connect to remote desktop over internet but its not working. Through lan it is working. I'm trying to find solution from last two days but no luck. I trying to connect to machine with windows 10 from windows 8.1.

Here is the Windows 10 configuration:

[image: Windows 10 configuration]

- Enabled Remote Desktop
- Enabled Remote Desktop app in firewall
- Enabled Rules for Remote Desktop
- Using default port number 3389
- netstat cmd is showing listening for 3389
- configured port forwarding in router

Here is the error in windows 8.1:

[image: In windows 8.1]

- Getting "Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons" error
- getting "Could not open connection to the host, on port 3389: Connect failed" when i run this command `telnet myip 3389`. Getting same error even when firewall is disabled completely.

**Edit:**
I have three different ips

1. 119.*.*.*     External IP (using to connect to my remote desktop)
2. 192.168.0.109 Internal IP (used for port forwarding)
3. 10.2.*.*      This is IP given by my ISP (Used to configure my router to access internet)

I didn't used my 3rd IP anywhere except for configuring my router to access internet

**Edit 2**

- removed all port forwarding from router, enabled only dmz and disabled firewall
- Tried connecting directly without router. still not working. Looks like my ISP blocked all the ports.

**Edit 3:**
There is no issue with my configuration. My ISP blocked the ports.

**Edit 4**
My ISP opened two ports for me. Finally I'm able to connect through Remote Desktop

@pat2015,@beeks,@Bilo Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: My ISP gave two ports for me. Finally I'm able to use Remote Desktop

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36309/discussion-on-question-by-mahindar-remote-desktop-not-working-over-wan). Also Mahindar, please edit out your solution from question and move it to an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was by default ports are closed. My ISP opened two ports for my IP address. Now I'm able to connect through Remote Desktop